# Promising being returned by method in VueJS throwing error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following page and I need to return true or false from the method check_user(), but I am actually getting a promise. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

`

```
<template>
    <NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>
    
    <div v-if="user_check() == false">
        User need to sign-up
    </div>
    
    <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
</template>

<script>
import router from '../router.js';
import NavbarComponent from '../components/NavbarComponent.vue';
import FooterComponent from '../components/FooterComponent.vue';

//import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'HomeView',

    components: {
        NavbarComponent,
        FooterComponent,
    },

    data(){
        return {
            companies_list: [],
            user_data: null,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        
        redirect_to_login_page(){
            router.push('/login');
        },

        redirect_to_home_page(){
            router.push('/')
        },

       async populate_user(){
            if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null == true){
                localStorage.setItem('user_data', 'user infos here');
                this.user_data = 'user infos here';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        async user_check() {
            try {
                const is_user_populated = await this.populate_user();
                return is_user_populated;
            } catch (error) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    },

}
</script>
```

`

I need the user_check() method to return a proper response (true or false) instead of returning a Promise object in the div below:

User need to sign-up

Comment: maybe set a variable to false and make your function set it to true when it returns a success that way you have a fallback value until the promise is resolved

Comment: Thanks for the response yehuda. I'm quite new to VueJS, would you mind sending me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

if your using async await you will always get a promise back, if you cant use a promise then i guess you can try this

```
<template>
    <NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>

    <div v-if="is_user_populated == false">
        User need to sign-up
    </div>

    <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
</template>

<script>
import router from '../router.js';
import NavbarComponent from '../components/NavbarComponent.vue';
import FooterComponent from '../components/FooterComponent.vue';

//import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'HomeView',

    components: {
        NavbarComponent,
        FooterComponent,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            companies_list: [],
            user_data: null,
            is_user_populated: false

        }
    },

    methods: {

        redirect_to_login_page() {
            router.push('/login');
        },

        redirect_to_home_page() {
            router.push('/')
        },

        populate_user() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null == true) {
                localStorage.setItem('user_data', 'user infos here');
                this.user_data = 'user infos here';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        user_check() {
            try {
                if (this.populate_user() == true) {
                    is_user_populated = true // or whatever you want it to be when there is a success
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: this way the variable that you are checking wont be a promise and it will have a default value, only when the user has been checked then the variable gets changed

Comment: you might want to refactor this a bit, try the vue <script setup>

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the error kept happening. Still receiving the same message. Any other ideas I might try?